# Xcode 4.4.1 checkout from subversion error

Tags: xcode, authentication, svn, svn-checkout

When I try to checkout from a subversion repository through Xcode 4.4.1 and after entering repository and subversion user information the following error returned:

**"Authentication realm: Assembla Restricted Area Password for ‘*UserName*’:Authentication realm: Assembla Restricted Area Username: svn: OPTIONS of ‘*Repository Path*’: authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (*Subversion Server*)"**

I ensured that subversion username and password are correct and when i connect using third party client it connects successfully.

How can i solve this???

Comment: Same problem as [this](http://plainoldstan.blogspot.se/2011/03/xcode-4svn-could-not-authenticate-to.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and after many attemps it was simply solved in two steps:
1- Checkout the solution using a subversion third party client(SCPlugin).
2- Open the project directly from Xcode and i can now commit and update project files through Xcode.